# All neutrals head back on bus bar?

Tags: hvac

I've only done basic wiring before and just writing to make sure I understand my circuit breakers wiring diagram so I don't blow anything up. I'm going from a Victron Multiplus-II mobile application Inverter running 12v Lithium, that has a 120v A/C out (L1/PE/N), going into a Blue Sea model 1214 120v breaker box, 30 AMP input and 2x 20AMP output heading to two 20 AMP GFCI/AFCI outlets.

What the back looks like (30 AMP breaker top two slots, bottom two slots each 20 AMP breakers):

[image]

Wiring diagram from Blue Sea that I annotated:

[image]

So the 30-AMP input side is pretty self explanatory:

1. I connect the black A/C HOT wire FROM Inverter L1 to BLUE circle.
2. I connect the white NEUTRAL wire FROM Inverter "N" to RED circle.
3. I connect the green GROUND wire FROM Inverter "PE" to GREEN circle.

1st 20-AMP breakers to outlets:

1. I connect the black A/C HOT wire FROM breaker circle YELLOW to HOT on outlet.
2. I connect the white NEUTRAL wire FROM AC outlets (loads) circle ORANGE to NEUTRAL on outlet. And that same NEUTRAL buss circled in ORANGE is connected to the SAME white wire that is connected to the 30-AMP breaker and heading BACK to Inverter "N". So all NEUTRALS from breakers and outlets all go back into Inverter "N"?
3. I connect the green GROUND wire FROM AC outlets (loads) to safety ground in GREEN circle connected TO "PE" on Inverter.

Repeat for 2nd-20 AMP breaker circled in purple to 2nd outlet.

Does this all sound correct? And correct me if I am wrong, the Inverter should also be connected to vehicle chassis ground, as is the 12v negative bus bar of my system.

Comment: Is this for a home or something else?